# How to insert newline character after comma in `),(` with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

How to insert newline character after comma in `),(` with sed?

```
$ more temp.txt
(foo),(bar)
(foobar),(foofoobar)

$ sed 's/),(/),\n(/g' temp.txt 
(foo),n(bar)
(foobar),n(foofoobar)
```

Why this doesn't work?

Comment: What platform and version of sed are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert newline (\n) using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082397/insert-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I know this question is old but I just had to wade trough this to make sed accept a \n character. I found a solution that works in bash and I am noting it here for others who run into the same problem.

To restate the problem: Get sed to accept the backslash escaped newline (or other backslash escaped characters for that matter).

The workaround in bash is to use:

```
$'\n'
```

In bash a $'\n' string is replaced with a real newline.

The only other thing you need to do is double escape the \n as you have to escape the slash itself.

To put it all together:

```
sed $'s/),(/),\\\n(/g' temp.txt
(foo),
(bar)
(foobar),
(foofoobar)
```

If you want it actually changed instead of being printed out use the -i

```
sed -i $'s/),(/),\\\n(/g' temp.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

`sed` does not support the `\n` escape sequence in its substitution command, however, it does support a real newline character if you escape it (because `sed` commands should only use a single line, and the escape is here to tell `sed` that you really want a newline character):

```
$ sed 's/),(/),\\
(/g' temp.txt
(foo),
(bar)
(foobar),
(foofoobar)
```

You can also use a shell variable to store the newline character.

```
$ NL='
'
$ sed "s/),(/,\\$NL(/g" temp.txt
(foo),
(bar)
(foobar),
(foofoobar)
```

Tested on Mac OS X Lion, using `bash` as shell.

Comment: In the first approach, why it needs to be `\\` but not `\`?

Comment: The command you pass to `sed` are not supposed to contains newline. So if you want to pass a newline, you need to escape it with a backslash so that `sed` know you did on purpose. And you need a second backslash to protect the first from being interpreted by the shell (using backslash to escape character in regexp was IMHO a bad idea since it is also generally used to quote character in string, and thus you usually have to use double backslash in regexp).

Answer (score 3):

You just have to escape with a backslash character and press the enter key while typing:

```
$ sed 's/),(/),\
(/g' temp.txt
(foo),
(bar)
(foobar),
(foofoobar)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you put the sed command in a bash file.  Only if you put `\\` before the new line character, it starts to work.  But I wonder why?

Comment: @user001 For what is worth, the exact same command worked for me in bash 4.2.10 in Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
$ echo "(foo),(bar)" | sed s/')','('/')',\\n'('/g
(foo),
(bar)
```

I am using:

- GNU sed 4.2.2
- GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)