# How to insert a new line of code in only perl scripts with Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a Linux folder tree with mixed shell, Perl and Python scripts. None of the scripts have consistent file extensions (.pl, .perl, .py, .sh, or no extension at all). I need to identify which files are Perl scripts, then add a new line of code to set a variable if the variable is not already in the Perl script.

Thanks to [How to insert newline character after comma in `),(` with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473060/how-to-insert-newline-character-after-comma-in-with-sed) I came up with this code that uses sed to insert the new line of code.

This code works, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
#! /bin/bash

NL='
$|++'

for f in `find "$1" -type f`
do
    if [ $(grep -cP "^\#\!/.+/perl" "${f}") -gt 0 ]
    then
        if [ $(grep -c "$|" "${f}") -eq 0 ]
        then
            sed -i -r "s/^#!\/(.+)\/perl(.+)$/#!\/\1\/perl\2\\${NL}/g" "${f}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of Useless Uses of Grep -c there.  See http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

```
#! /bin/bash

NL='
$|++'

for f in `find "$1" -type f`
do
    grep -qP "^\#\!/.+/perl" "${f}" &&
    ! grep -q "$|" "${f}" &&
    sed -i -r "s/^#!\/(.+)\/perl(.+)$/#!\/\1\/perl\2\\${NL}/g" "${f}"
done
```

The short-circuit `&&` is not an optimization, just a personal preference.  You could just as well keep your nested `if`s, or perhaps something like

```
    if grep -qP "^#!/.+/perl" "$f" && ! grep -q "$|" "$f"; then ...
```

It might be more efficient still to do the first grep (at least) in a `sed` script since presumably you are only interested in the first line of the script.  (On the other hand, why do you have a `/g` flag on the `sed` substitution if that is the case?)

Actually you probably mean

```
    sed -i -r "1s%^(#!/.+/perl.*)$%\1\\${NL}%" "$f"
```

Comment: Thank you Tripleee. This is much faster because grep doesn't search the whole file with -q. Why did I have the /g? Because I didn't know what I was doing :) Yes, I used your suggested alternative. Please note your substitution adds an extra "#!/" because it was captured in the group. I removed it. Thanks again.

Comment: Oops; fixed.  Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `file(1)` command:

```
$ head -n 1 perl_script_wo_ext
#!/usr/bin/perl
$ file perl_script_wo_ext
perl_script_wo_ext: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

Then grep for `\bPerl script\b` in that and you're set.