# Bash Sed replace

Tags: bash, sed

I'm working in a Zend CRUD generator and I have to replace the word "test" which is in $targetForm file with the form code of each field.

```
field[0]="foo"
field[1]="bar"

textareafield='$'"acme_en = new Utils_Form_Element_Textarea('acme_en',array('langblock'=>'en', 'isWysiwyg' => true));
    "'$'"this->addElement("'$'"acme_en);
    "'$'"this->addElement('textarea','acme_fr', array( 'label'=>__('acme'), 'langblock'=>'fr', 'isWysiwyg' => true, 'altLangElem' => "'$'"acme_en));"    

for ((i=0; i<${#field[@]}; i++));
do
    formfield[$i]=$textareafield
    formfield[$i]=${formfield[$i]//acme/${field[$i]}}
    echo ${formfield[$i]}
    sed -i "s/test/test\n        ${formfield[$i]}/" $targetForm
done
```

The command line says:

```
$foo_en = new Utils_Form_Element_Textarea('foo_en', array('langblock'=>'en', 'isWysiwyg' => true)); $this->addElement($foo_en); $this->addElement('textarea','foo_fr', array( 'label'=>__('foo'), 'langblock'=>'fr', 'isWysiwyg' => true, 'altLangElem' => $foo_en));
sed: -e expression #1, char 120: unterminated `s' command
$bar_en = new Utils_Form_Element_Textarea('bar_en', array('langblock'=>'en', 'isWysiwyg' => true)); $this->addElement($bar_en); $this->addElement('textarea','bar_fr', array( 'label'=>__('bar'), 'langblock'=>'fr', 'isWysiwyg' => true, 'altLangElem' => $bar_en));
sed: -e expression #1, char 120: unterminated `s' command
```

Maybe there's a problem with the specials character but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error you get very likely has nothing to do with using `\n` in `sed` substitution (especially since you mentioned in the comments that you are using `GNU sed version 4.2.1`).

---

The real culprit is `textareafield` which contains a multi-line string.

What happens is that when `${formfield[$i]}` gets expanded, your `sed` command looks like this

```
sed -i "s/test/test\n        line1
line2
line3/"
```

This is problematic because without terminating lines with a literal `\`, `sed` would interpret each line as a complete command in itself, in this case

```
s/test/test\n        line1
```

which is missing a `/` at the end, hence the error "**unterminated `s' command**".

To fix this, what we want is to insert a `\` to the end of every line except the last, i.e.

```
sed -i "s/test/test\n        line1\
line2\
line3/"
```

I got your example to work by adding two lines

```
for ((i=0; i<${#field[@]}; i++));
do
    formfield[$i]=$textareafield
    formfield[$i]=${formfield[$i]//acme/${field[$i]}}
    formfield[$i]=${formfield[$i]//\;/\;\\}
    formfield[$i]=${formfield[$i]%\\}
    echo ${formfield[$i]}
    sed -i "s/test/test\n        ${formfield[$i]}/" $targetForm
done
```

Since all the lines in `textareafield` end in `;`, I replaced all `;` with `;\`, then removed the last `\` from the last line.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` [does not support `\n` in the substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473060/how-to-insert-newline-character-after-comma-in-with-sed), but you can use a literal newline if you escape it. Also, you need to quote the `'` characters. Here is one way of doing it:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#field[@]}; i++));
do
    formfield[$i]=$textareafield
    formfield[$i]=${formfield[$i]//acme/${field[$i]}}
    sedexpr="${formfield[$i]}"
    sedexpr="${sedexpr//\'/\'}"
    sedexpr="${sedexpr//
/\\
}"
    sed -i "s/test/test\
        ${sedexpr}/" $targetForm
done
```

But at this level of complexity you're probably better off switching to something like Python.

Comment: It doesn't works but anyway, in other part of my code it works: `sed -i "s/<!--fieldshere-->/<!--fieldshere-->\n            ${line[$i]}/" $targetViewForm`

Comment: Which version of sed are you running, and on which operating system?

Comment: GNU sed version 4.2.1; Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: with `textareafield="acme-test"` it works, that's why I think the problem is with the ' character.

Comment: It works if I delete the new line in the variable `textareafield='$'"acme_en = new Utils_Form_Element_Textarea('acme_en', array('langblock'=>'en', 'isWysiwyg' => true)); "'$'"this->addElement('textarea','acme_fr', array( 'label'=>__('acme'), 'langblock'=>'fr', 'isWysiwyg' => true, 'altLangElem' => "'$'"acme_en));"` And with \n in the Sed line Thanks!

Comment: Turns out you need to quote both `'` and newlines. See the revised version.