# Insert newline (\n) using sed

Tags: bash, sed, freebsd

I am trying to scrub some lists into a properly formatted CSV file for database import.

My starting file, looks something like this with what is supposed to be each "line" spanning multiple lines like below

```
Mr. John Doe
Exclusively Stuff, 186 
Caravelle Drive, Ponte Vedra
33487.
```

I created a `sed` script that cleans up the file (there's lots of "dirty" formatting like double spaces and spaces before/after commas).  **The problem is the Zip with the period.**  I would like to change that period for a new line, but I cannot get it to work.

The command that I use is:

```
sed -E -f scrub.sed test.txt
```

and the `scrub.sed` script is as follows:

```
:a
N
s|[[:space:]][[:space:]]| |g
s|,[[:space:]]|,|g
s|[[:space:]],|,|g
s|\n| |g
s|[[:space:]]([0-9]{5})\.|,FL,\1\n |g
$!ba
```

What I get is

```
Mr. John Doe,Exclusively Stuff,186 Caravelle Drive,Ponte Vedra,FL,33487n
```

If figured that the Zip+.(period) would be a great "delimiter" to use the substitution on and while I can find it, I can't seem to tell it to put a newline there.

Most of the things I found online are about replacing the newline with something else (usually deleting them), but not much on replacing with a newline.  I did find this, but it didn't work:  [How to insert newline character after comma in `),(` with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473060/how-to-insert-newline-character-after-comma-in-with-sed)

Is there something I am missing?

Update:

I edited my scrub.sed file putting the literal new line as instucted.  It still doesn't work

```
:a
N
s|[[:space:]][[:space:]]| |g
s|,[[:space:]]|,|g
s|[[:space:]],|,|g
s|\n| |g
s|[[:space:]]([0-9]{5})\.|,FL,\1\
|g
$!ba
```

What I get is (everything on one line):

```
Mr. John Doe,Exclusively Stuff,186 Caravelle Drive,Ponte Vedra,FL,33487 Mrs. Jane Smith,Props and Stuff,123 Main Drive,Jacksonville,FL,336907
```

My expected output should be:

```
Mr. John Doe,Exclusively Stuff,186 Caravelle Drive,Ponte Vedra,FL,33487
Mrs. Jane Smith,Props and Stuff,123 Main Drive,Jacksonville,FL,336907
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine here. With the same file and script I get the data reformatted with a newline at the end. Putting `\n\n` in the penultimate line of your sed script gives me two newlines as expected. (I don't get a comma between "Doe" and "Exclusively" however).

I'm using (GNU sed) 4.4 on Linux. Which version/platform are you using?

Comment: I am using `sed` on FreeBSD

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps try with GNU sed, if that's an option?

I also see that I am getting the ",FL," in the output as you seem to want from the script. Are you sure the output you're providing is coming from the script you're providing?

Comment: It's correct.  I inadvertently deleted the FL when trying to obfuscate the real data.

Comment: Consider not removing the newline after the zip code.  Change `s|\n| |g` to `s|\([^[:space:]]\)\n\([^[:space:]]\)|\1 \2|g` so that only newlines with a character after them are transformed.  Then you don't have to reinstate what you didn't remove.

Comment: You said `I can't seem to tell it to put a newline there.` and asked for help to do so. I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46082547/1745001) showing the portable way to do so and you said `it doesn't answer my question`. So, please [edit] your question to make it clear what your real question is so no-one else wastes time answering the wrong question.

Comment: Or, since you seem to be using extended regexes, then you can use fewer backslashes:  `s|([^[:space:]])\n([^[:space:]])|\1 \2|g`.  Since you're working with a script file (probably sensible -- I like using script files too) instead of command-line arguments to `sed`, you can add the backslash newline mentioned in the answer by putting a backslash at the end of a line and the rest of the material on the next line.  It would be trickier if you were working with `-e '...'` options on the command line.

Comment: @jww - I *literally* referenced that post in my question and stated that it **didn't work.**

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The `sed` on BSD does not support the `\n` representation of a new line (turning it into a literal `n`):

```
$ echo "123." | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]*)\./\1\n next line/'
123n next line
```

GNU `sed` does support the `\n` representation:

```
$ echo "123." | gsed -E 's/([[:digit:]]*)\./\1\nnext line/'
123
next line
```

Alternatives are:

Use a single character delimiter that you then use `tr` translate into a new line:

```
$ echo "123." | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]*)\./\1|next line/' | tr '|' '\n'
123
next line
```

Or use an escaped literal new line in your sed script:

```
$ echo "123." | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]*)\./\1\
next line/'
123
next line
```

Or define a new line:

POSIX:

```
nl='
'
```

BASH / zsh / others that support [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
nl=$'\n'
```

And then use `sed` with appropriate quoting and escapes to insert the literal `\n`:

```
echo "123." | sed 's/\./'"\\${nl}"'next line/'
123
next line
```

Or use `awk`:

```
$ echo "123." | awk '/^[[:digit:]]+\./{sub(/\./,"\nnext line")} 1'
123
next line
```

Or use GNU sed which supports `\n`

Comment: I am attempting to use the escaped literal in my sed script as shown but for whatever reason, it's not working.  However, re:  what you said about BSD not supporting `\n`, I will shift my strategy to incorporate `tr`.  I never would have guessed it wasn't supported.  Thanks!

Comment: *I am attempting to use the escaped literal in my sed script as shown but for whatever reason, it's not working.* It is hard to do in a `sed` script vs a one line `sed`. You can also use a multi character delimiter (say `<!!>`) and then use `awk` to change that into a `\n`. To be honest, POSIX `sed` is best used for single line changes only.

Comment: Adding a literal newline in a script is no harder than on the command line - the syntax doesn't change. Obviously you'd never REALLY insert a character or string and then convert it to newlines later by a pipe to some other command as that's just unnecessarily fragile and inefficient. The OPs remaining problem has nothing to do with this though, [what I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46082547/1745001) works just fine for the question he asked and his problem now is with another part of his script (the `s|,[[:space:]]|,|g` in his loop is removing the newline after it was added).

Comment: @EdMorton: I guess I did not try and debug his script with the literal new line. I do remember (as a BSD user) head scratching times were I felt it *should* work but did not.

Comment: Yeah and Solaris sed is even worse. If it's not simply `s/old/new/` then you're into different combinations of jumbled runes involving every punctuation mark, single letter and the batman symbol, with the meaning of each changing on a sed-by-sed, box-by-box basis. Hence awk.... :-).

Comment: So that it works replace `gsed` with `sed`. Easy one.

Comment: `sed  '/ags=\[/a \n' $cv` Append a new line after ags=\[ results in `n` on a new line. I use WSL2 Debian

Comment: @EdMorton can't wait to see a sed example with batman symbols

Answer (score 17):

The portable way to get a newline in sed is a backslash followed by a literal newline:

```
$ echo 'foo' | sed 's/foo/foo\
bar/'
foo
bar
```

I guarantee there's a far simpler solution to your whole problem by using awk rather than sed though.

Answer (score 3):

The following works on Oracle Linux, x8664:

```
$ echo 'foobar' | sed 's/foo/foo\n/'
foo
bar
```

If you need it to match more than once per line, you'll need to place a `g` at the end, as in:

```
$ echo 'foobarfoobaz' | sed 's/foo/foo\n/g'
foo
barfoo
baz
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add a line after a match.**

The sed command can add a new line after a pattern match is found. The "a" command to sed tells it to add a new line after a match is found.

> sed '/unix/ a "Add a new line"' file.txt

```
unix is great os. unix is opensource. unix is free os.

    "Add a new line"
    
    learn operating system.
    
    unixlinux which one you choose.
    
    "Add a new line"
```

**Add a line before a match**

The sed command can add a new line before a pattern match is found. The "i" command to sed tells it to add a new line before a match is found.

> sed '/unix/ i "Add a new line"' file.txt

```
"Add a new line"

unix is great os. unix is opensource. unix is free os.

learn operating system.

"Add a new line"

unixlinux which one you choose.
```

Comment: lol - unix is famously NOT open source. ;)

Comment: nice. it worked you got the point.