# Replace '>' with '>\n' in several files in shell/bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, tr

I have several files in a single folder and I want to replace the character `>` with `>\n` everywhere in all of those files.

But whatever I do, the `\n` character does not get added after the `>` character.

I have tried the following:

```
echo '>ABCCHACAC' | tr '\>' '>\\n'
echo '>ABCCHACAC' | tr '>' '>\\n'
echo '>ABCCHACAC' | tr '>' '>\n'
echo '>ABCCHACAC' | tr '>' '\>\n'
echo '>ABCCHACAC' | tr '>' '\>\\n'
echo '>ABCCHACAC' | tr '>' '\>\\n'
```

But I get the same input string as output, whereas the correct output I want is:

```
>
ABCCHACAC
```

And I am using this script to do the same thing on many files:

```
for f in *.txt
do
  tr ">" ">\n" < "$f" > $(basename "$f" .txt)_newline_added.txt
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr` is for one-for-one character replacements, not replacing strings. E.g. if you translate `abc` with `def`, it replaces all `a` with `d`, all `b` with `e`, and all `c` with `f`. When the second string is longer than the first, the extra characters are ignored. So `tr '>' '>\n'` means to replace `>` with `>` and ignores `\n`.

Use `sed` to perform string replacements.

```
sed 's/>/>\n/g' "$f" > "$(basename "$f" .txt)_newline_added.txt"
```

Comment: Great answer. Exactly what I was looking for. I only think that you missed a crucial, third delimiter (that is, `/`) at the end of your sed expression right after `\n` inside the quotation marks. Therefore, the correct expression would be: `sed 's/>/>\n/'`

Comment: @votresignu Right, I also forgot the `g` modifier to do multiple replacements per line.

Comment: Would the `g` be essential if I have only and only one `>` character per each line?

Comment: No, but there's nothing in the question that suggests this constraint on the input file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Barmar's answer, if you're using a BSD based *nix (eg. OS X) you'll either need to include an escaped literal newline, or possibly use `tr` in addition to `sed`.

**Escaped literal newline:**

```
$ sed 's/^>/>\
/' "$f"
```

**`sed`** *with* **`tr`:**

```
$ sed 's/^>/>▾/' "$f" | tr '▾' '\n'
```

↳ [Insert newline (\n) using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46082397/499581)