# How to replace '. ' with '.\n' using MacOS sed?

Tags: macos, sed

I want to start each sentence from a new line by changing '. ' to '.\n'.
The solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190985/how-to-put-sentences-on-separate-lines-on-linux

```
sed 's/[.]  */&\n/g' text.txt
```

doesn't work on MacOS:

```
sed: 1: "s/.
": unterminated substitute pattern
```

How to fix it to run on MacOS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert newline (\n) using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46082547/3832970)

Comment: It does answer, but does not work.

Comment: Try `sed "s/\\./&"$'\\\n'"/g" file`

Comment: `sed: 1: "text.txt": command a expects \ followed by text`

Comment: The best you can do is install a GNU `sed` and enjoy a far bugfree tool.

Comment: or use `perl -pe 's/\.\h*\K/\n/g'`