# Using Sed -i option in AIX servers. function cannot be parsed aix

Tags: linux, sed, scripting, aix

I am trying to parse a file in AIX server. I could do the name in Ubuntu.

As the `-i` option did not work, i used a temperory file and renamed that to the original file. Please let me know where I am missing something.

I have to find a pattern in the file and add a line above or below the pattern.

```
sed '/ServiceNow (TAM):/i myline1' filename > temp_file && mv temp_file filename
```

Actual commands used:

```
sed '/ServiceNow (TAM)/i servicenow.test..ersngrouplist.0=Test' /itim/data/testfile > temp_properties && mv temp_properties /itim/data/testfile
```

Error:
sed: Function /ServiceNow (TAM)/i servicenow.test..ersngrouplist.0=Test cannot be parsed.

Please help how i can change this command to get

My Expectation:

myline1
ServiceNow (TAM):  //pattern
myline2

Comment: Sorry, but that is not enough information. We would need some *actual* example data, the *actual* commands you typed, and the *actual* error / output. Ideally as short and concise as possible ([mcve]). Posting pseudocode ("pattern" / "new_line" and saying "it failed" does not tell us anything, and we cannot help you that way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated with actual commands. Will this helps now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert newline using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082397/).

Comment: Just a thought... when working with the *"awkward"* Unix platforms (without wishing to shame anyone, but I mean HP-UX, AIX and Tru64) I generally found that **Perl** was far, far more consistent across them all and resorted time and again to **Perl** to get solutions that worked across the board. Tim Maher's excellent book *"Minimal Perl"* discusses all the variants of `awk`, `sed` and `grep` and shows how to overcome the differences with Perl.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that POSIX versions of `sed` don't accept the `i` command with additional text on the same line. You need to put a `\` after `i` and to put the text for insertion on the next line.

```
sed '/ServiceNow (TAM)/i\
servicenow.test..ersngrouplist.0=Test'
```

The error message from GNU `sed` is far more helpful than AIX's!

```
$ sed --posix '/ServiceNow (TAM)/i servicenow.test..ersngrouplist.0=Test'
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'
```