# How to insert newline in the argument text of "sed" utility under both single and double quotes?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, utility

I'd like to insert multiple lines above a target line in a file by using sed.

The `file.txt` below contains one line "`target line`". My initial version is using the single quote:

```bash
sed '/target line/ i\
     inserted line1;\
     inserted line2;\
     inserted line3;' file.txt
```

The result is:

```bash
    inserted line1;
    inserted line2;
    inserted line3;
target line
```

This version works as expected that the newline at the end of each line is escaped by `\` to a literal newline instead of a command terminator. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083970/15596097).

Then I'd like to use shell variable in the replacement string, so I tried to use double quotes to enable the variable expansion:

```bash
sed "/target line/ i\
     inserted line1;\
     inserted line2;\
     inserted line3;" file.txt
```

But this time the newline and the first four spaces disappeared:

```bash
inserted line1;    inserted line2;    inserted line3;
target line
```

How do I correctly insert a newline in double quotes here?

Comment: Please, do not show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Comment: IMHO it is best to encapsulate sed commands in single quotes and when needed, punch-a-hole through to the shell beneath by closing the existing command with a single quote, doing some shell e.g showing a shell variable `"${someVariable}"` and then opening another. Using double quotes to encapsulate sed commands leads to weird side effects which can be difficult to diagnose or even realise have happened. BTW to include a single quote, punch-a-hole and in the hole enter `\'`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Hi, thank you for the reminder and reference. I'll edit the question to remove the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With single-quotes**:

The backslash followed by the newline are transmitted as-is to sed. Then sed actually uses the backslash to escape the raw newline character into the string rather than terminating the command. See:

```bash
$ printf %s 'hello\
world' | hexdump -C
```

Which clearly shows the backslash `5c` followed by the newline `0a` contained in the string.

```
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 5c 0a 77  6f 72 6c 64              |hello\.world|
0000000c
```

**With double-quotes**:

The backslash has special meaning in double-quotes. It causes the following newline character to be interpreted as a string continuation character. The consequence is that neither the backslash or the newline are contained in the string and so not seen by sed.

```bash
$ printf %s "hello\
world" | hexdump -C
```

The string is continued without backslash and without newline:

```
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 77 6f 72  6c 64                    |helloworld|
0000000a
```

---

**EDIT**:

- Precised that sed actually uses the backslash to escape the following newline character as [@dan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72795679/how-do-single-and-double-quotes-affect-the-behavior-of-the-newline-in-replacemen/72797189#comment128587238_72797808).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the insights. Based on the explanation, can I say the third example in my question works because the newline `\n` I typed "explicitly" in the string is not captured by the sed as a command terminator, but a character in the string as-is, and the `\\` after it causes the "implicit" newline become a line continuation instead of a terminator as well?

Comment: @taoistmiao in the 3ʳᵈ example, you don't need the backslash at the begging of the 2ⁿᵈ line. Otherwise you got it quite wrong. In double-quote context `\n` is invalid and should be written `\\n`; then it would end-up transmitted as `\n` literally to sed, which by chance you use GNU sed which know to decode `\n` into an actual newline. Because of double-quote, the last backslash at the end of the line is decoded by the shell as a string continuation and so is never seen by sed.

Answer (score 2):

In double quotes, backslash escapes these characters (only):

```
$`"\
```

and newline character. So eg `echo "\$"` prints `$`.

To preserve the backslash in double quotes, escape it with another backslash:

```
 sed "/target line/ i\\
     inserted line1;\\
     inserted line2;\\
     inserted line3;" file.txt
```

Comment: Poster wanted to preserve newlines, not those backslashes. The right answer to this is just remove the backslashes at all, sed just ignores them unless you need to pass a backslash to sed to escape Regex grammar elements.

Comment: @LéaGris That's not correct. The (single) backslashes are required to escape the raw new lines in the text to be inserted. OP (presumably) wishes to insert 3 lines before the matching line.

Comment: @LéaGris From POSIX: "The argument _text_ shall consist of one or more lines. Each embedded <newline> in the text shall be preceded by a <backslash>. Other <backslash> characters in text shall be removed, and the following character shall be treated literally." _text_ refers to the argument to the `i` command. Implentations like GNU sed also expand `\t` and so on. But raw newlines here must be escaped, or they are treated as command terminators

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. This is the rational solution to my original problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not imperative to use sed, there are much easier ways of doing this.

```
#!/bin/sh

var1=foo
var2=bar
var3=baz

cat > stack <<EOF
${var1}
${var2}
${var3}
EOF
```

You can likewise create a here document for use with ed, to insert lines before existing ones.

```
cat > ed1 <<EOF
1i
line1
line2
line3
.
wq
EOF

ed -s existing_file < ed1
```

That will insert those three lines before line 1 in your existing file, so that what was the first line will become line 4.